# Was out hunting / was hunting

Tags: meaning

> The three goddesses agreed on one thing: that the most handsome and fashionably dressed mortal who walked on the face of the earth was Paris, Prince of Troy. They decided to surprise him. **One day when Paris was out hunting on the foothills of Mount Ida, he discovered three lovely goddesses standing beneath a tree.**

What is the difference between "was hunting" and "was out hunting"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Was hunting* means that he was engaged in the activity of hunting, without saying where he was doing it.

*Was out hunting* means that he was somewhere out, away from his home or base, to hunt.

Given the nature of *hunting*, there's probably no difference in this case. But *He was out drinking* says something different from *He was drinking*.